# laravel auth() is not allowing a user to make a post request

Tags: php, laravel

A user should be able to set a rating for more than one book, it allows a user to set a rating for ONLY one book, but not any other.

**The problem**

> the user is not able to make another rating for
>   another book. However, another user
>   can make a rating for the same book, but cant make another rating for
>   other books. Not even if the user logged out.

I'm using [rateYo](http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/) and [laravel-ratable](https://github.com/willvincent/laravel-rateable)

The way i have it set up,  a rating `type` is set to false by default, enabling a user to set stars and make a rating pretty much.

And once again, once a user makes a rating for any book doesn't matter which, the rating `type` is set to true which disables a user to set a star.

Here is what i have

here is how the html setup is like

**HTML**

```
  <div id="rateYo" data-rateyo-rating="{{  $book->userSumRating or 0}}" data-rateyo-read-only="{{ $book->rated ? 'true' : 'false' }}"></div`>
```

**BookController.php**

```
  public function rate(Request $request, $book_id)
    {

        $book = Book::find($book_id);
        $rating = $book->ratings()->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();

        if(is_null($rating)){
            $ratings = new Rating();
            $ratings->rating =  $request['rating'];
            $ratings->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $ratings->type = Book::RATED;
            $book->ratings()->save($ratings);



            return json_encode($book);

        }
        else{
           return response()->json(['status' => 'You already left a review']);
        }
    }

    public function show($book_name)
    {
        $books = Book::GetBook($book_name)->get();


        $data = $books->map(function(Book $book){


            $book['rated'] =  $book->type; 

            return $book;

        });

        return view('books.show', compact('data', $data));
    }
```

**Book.php**(relevant code) On default if a rating has not been set, type is equal to false enabling the user to make a rating, if a rating is set, type is equal to true disabling the star feature/read mode.

```
use Rateable;

const RATED = "true";
const NOT_RATED = "false";

protected $fillable = [ 'user_id', 'title', 'description'];

protected $appends = ['rated'];


public function getRatedAttribute()
{
    return Rate::where('type',  $this->owl() )->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id )->first();
}


public function owl(){

    foreach($this->rate as $rates){
        if ($rates->type != "true"){
            return self::NOT_RATED;
        }

    }
    return self::RATED;

}


public function rate()
{   
    return $this->hasMany('App\Rate', 'type', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: Please show the code how you are passing this `$book_id` from frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the book id in the where clause to check if the user has left a rating for that particular book. As you have it it will find the first rating a user has left for *any* book.

```
$constraints = [
    'user_id' => auth()->id(),
    'book_id' => $book_id
];

// checks if the user has not left a rating for this particular book
if ($book->ratings()->where($constraints)->doesntExist()) {
    // create new rating...
} else {
    // user has already rated this book...
}
```

Comment: this was actually the book model

Comment: im about try this out, where does this code go into,im kind of confused.

Answer (score 0):

i need to change my Book model to the following, thank you digital for steering me into the right direction

**Book.php**

```
public function getRatedAttribute()
{
    $this->constraints = [
        'user_id' => auth()->id()
    ];

    if(Rating::where($this->constraints)->exists()){

        return Rating::where(['type' => self::RATED, 'book_id' => $this->getKey()])->first();
    }else{
        return Rating::where('type' ,self::NOT_RATED)->first();
    }

}
```